# Collecting 5G cell data (New Radio)

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-10.0, cellinfo

After doing some digging I’ve found google source code containing 5G information related to as NR (new radio). Interestingly enough, these changes are not available on dev or pie-dev but on the master branch!

telephony manager incl. 5g
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java

CellInfo class for 5g
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/CellInfoNr.java

List of 5g telephony classes:

- CellIdentityNr.java
- CellInfoNr.java
- CellSignalStrengthNr.java

I would like my app to start supporting 5G before the first 5G phone is out which is soon but the new classes are not in the SDK I'm building with (28) Do I need to wait for Android Q ? What was the story with 4G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Software Development Kit 29 (Android-Q) is now accessible allowing us to implement 5G collection methods.
The official documentation is now updated listing the values we've seen on Google's development branches:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityNr.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthNr.html

Comment: it does not appear in my android studio, what do i have to do ?